# Are there any tools to visualize a complicated SQL join?

Tags: sql, visualization

Given that many frameworks will create complicated (and maybe not so readable/logical) SQL queries, it would seem that having a tool to show, visually, how the joins were done might be a helpful tool.  But I have not found such a tool.

I took a query that included a lot of tables and created a graphic as an example of what I think would be the output from such a tool:
[image: manually generated visualization]

The text on the links are the field names that are used in the join.  The bold items are inputs to the query.  The table names ending in digits are just repeat instances of the same table (ie Partner and Partner2 are the same table, just part of the query more than once).

I would like to be able to drop an SQL query into a tool and see a diagram like this.  Possible?

Answer (score 3):

I found this tool, it might be useful.

http://queryviz.com/online/

Although the SQL syntax supported looks to be quite limited..

Comment: I'd say **very** limited: the tool does not even the `JOIN` operator

Comment: Are you sure? There are many JOINs in their examples given.

Comment: I'm talking about the `JOIN` operator (`select * from a join b on a.id = b.id`), not the totally outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Comment: I see. I would say this is usual in academia prototypes.

Comment: It doesn't support CROSS APPLY.

Comment: queryviz is rather limited in what it can do. If you are looking for an advanced tool where you can toggle between code and SQL code visualisation have a look at FlowHigh SQL Visualiser. I have wrutten up a blog post about it here: https://sonra.io/flowhigh/from-code-to-clarity-visualizing-sql-code-for-documentation-and-debugging/

Disclaimer: I work for Sonra

Answer (score 0):

You can get this sort of output using SQL Analyzer with SQL Server. Something similar exists for postgresql: I've never seen anything graphical for MySql or Oracle.

In other words: nothing generic (which is perhaps what one would expect given the complex and individual nature of database optimizer engines).

Comment: I'm on Oracle.  Dave, Can you see the diagram?  I've just got a single pixel.  Oh, wait, it's my lovely megacorp blocking imgur.

Comment: @Dale: well, In Oracle you can get the explain plan easily enough: but translating that to graphical output is not available out of the box (at least, not that I'm aware of).

Comment: Maybe that's a tool for me to write... explain plan to visualization.  When I get some free time, hahahah!

Comment: "*Something similar exists for postgresql*" - do you have a link for that? Or at least the name of the tool?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: there is a basic explain-plan representation that comes with pgAdmin: http://www.pgadmin.org/